# Retrieving Snyk's vulnerability alerts in Splunk

Tags: security, snyk

How could one retrieve `Snyk`'s vulnerabilities into `Splunk`?

I am thinking the Splunk OpenTelemetry Collector could be a good integration point, but willing to know if someone has a parser before writing my own.

Would love to hear suggestions on the right integration and possible parser or script?

Comment: This can be your starting point https://www.kimpel.com/post/snyk/forward-snyk-vuln-data-to-splunk/